# How to start an intent that extends fragment, from a class that extends Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have problem starting an `intent` that extends `Fragment`, from a class that extends `Activity`.

**TabBar2.class --> extends Activity**

**Favourite.class --> extends Fragment**

This is how I write my intent.

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(TabBar2.this, Favourite.class);
startActivity(intent1);
```

But my app crashes when I run the intent when `onClick`.
My logCat says

```
Unable to instantiate activity
 ComponentInfo{com.honey.test/com.honey.test.Favourite}:
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.honey.test.Favourite
```

What did I do wrong? Can someone guide me on how to solve this?

Comment: Check thi one `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831728/start-a-fragment-via-intent-within-a-fragment`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because you can't call Fragments via Intent, Fragment is a part of an FragmentActivity

All in all Fragment is a content not container, so you need to create a FragmentActivity and add Fragment(Favourite) in that, and then call

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(TabBar2.this, SomeFragmentActivity.class);
startActivity(intent1);
```

`A Fragment is a piece of an application's user interface or behavior that can be placed in an Activity` [**more information**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Comment: @hotveryspicy Nice answer & description ++

Comment: describe in detail i dint get.