# How to remove error : create method 'getApplicationContext()' and 'runOnUiThread(Runnable)' when extends Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-context

When I am using the `getApplicationContext()` that time eclipse give me error `create method 'getApplicationContext()'`. Please let me know How to remove this error. I am try also using **ClassName.this** that time error like `change method startListening(Context) to  startListening(Main)`

Also when I use like : `measurement_index = AppSettings.getMeasureUnit(this);`
 then Error like :`change method getMeasureUnit(Context) to  getMeasureUnit(Main)`

So please let me know how can solve error like:

1. create method 'getApplicationContext()'
2. change method getMeasureUnit(Context) to  getMeasureUnit(Main)

Check my code.

**Main.class**

```
public class Main extends Fragment implements GPSCallback{

....... 

public static Fragment newInstance(int position) {
    Main f = new Main();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

     ...

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);

    /*Intent in = new Intent(Main.this,MainDisplay.class);
              // ------------> Here give error like : Remove arguments match to Intent();
    startActivity(in);*/

    tv_display_Speed = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.speed_display);

     gpsManager = new GPSManager();

        gpsManager.startListening(getApplicationContext());
                   //------------>  Eclipse give me error create method 'getApplicationContext()'

        gpsManager.setGPSCallback(this);

        //(TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.speed_display);

        measurement_index = AppSettings.getMeasureUnit(this);
                   //------------> Here Give me error like : change method getMeasureUnit(Context) to  getMeasureUnit(Main) 


    btnstart = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button_start);
    btnstart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }
    });

    return root;
}
```

**startListening** method:

```
public void startListening(final Context context)
{
     ....
}
```

**getMeasureUnit** method:

```
public static int public static int getMeasureUnit(Context context){
    return getInt(context,AppSettings.UNIT_STRING);
}
```

**EDIT :**

I have Added the `onStart()` method into above class that extends fragment.
That time at `runOnUiThread(updateTask);` Eclipse give me error like : `create method runOnUiThread(Runnable)` .Please let me know how can I achieve this.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    timer = new Timer("DigitalClock");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Get the Current Time
    final Runnable updateTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            txt_display_clock.setText(getCurrentTimeString()); // shows the current
                                                        // time of the day

        }
    };

    // update the UI
    int msec = 999 - calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(updateTask); // <---------------- HERE
        }
    }, msec, 1000);
}
```

Comment: `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` will do.

Comment: @hotveryspicy I want exact opposite from http://stackoverflow.com/a/13132567/1263679 , means intent from `fragment to activity` is it possible?

Comment: @hotveryspicy When I added the `onstart()` method then when using `runOnUiThread(updateTask);` that time error like : create method runOnUiThread(Runnable);  Please check my updated code. and give me solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a Fragment, you can use `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` instead.

As for the AppSettings.getMeasureUnit error, if the getMeasureUnit method is expecting a context you can usually use `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Thanks, it's done. and waht about the second error `measurement_index = AppSettings.getMeasureUnit(this);`. can i use `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` in place of `this`?

Comment: When I added the `onstart()` method then when using `runOnUiThread(updateTask);` that time error like : create method runOnUiThread(Runnable);  Please check my updated code. and give me solution.