# Error while setting Notification in Android

Tags: android, notifications

Im getting error at `getApplicationContext()` when I am setting an notification in my app through my adapter class which extends `PagerAdapter`. Below is my code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,6);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);               
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 26);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,12);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,31);
//cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
Intent alarmintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmintent.putExtra("title","Reminder");
alarmintent.putExtra("note"," is in few minutes.");
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), HELLO_ID,
        alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
//  AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

can anyone plz help me.
Best Regards.

Comment: what error are you getting? copy/paste from logcat. If it is `NullPointerException` that you are getting, try using your `activity context`

Comment: Can you try putting the current context instead of Application context.

Comment: Im getting error "create method getApplicationContext()"

Comment: maybe this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13523542/1276374

Comment: When I use the same code with Activity context, 1)Intent alarmintent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);2)AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); at this time no errors but Im unable to set alarm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save context of your calling activiy in a private variable of your adapter class. and pass that to constructor of intent instead of getApplicationContext().

```
private myAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
private Context mContext;
.
.
.
public myAdapter(Context context,........... ) {

super(context,  ......);
this.mContext = context;
.
.
}



//now in constructor of Intent
Intent alarmintent = new Intent(mContext, AlarmReceiver.class);
//also in pending intent
```

Comment: I used Activity context; will this do

Comment: please elaborate more i assume you want to say you passed your constructor <code> myAdapter(Activity context,......) </code> than you can simply make your private variable to be <code> private Activity mContext </code>