# The method getApplicationContext() is undefined and the constructor DatePickerDialog is undefined

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

I have gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523526/how-to-remove-error-create-method-getapplicationcontext-and-runonuithread). But the given solution does not solve my problem. All well experienced persons suggested to use `getActivty().getApplicationContext()`. But I'm using a normal class instead of activity. I'm getting all the UI values and initialized to the objects which is in my fragment. So from there I tried to save it in my database. I'm using normal class for database which is not extending anything.

I'm getting two errors when I pass the values from my main fragment to database class:

1. The constructor DatePickerDialog(TopRatedFragment, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, int, int, int) is undefined
2. create method getApplicationContext()

Please give me some idea to solve this problem.

Here is my Fragment class code.

```
public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment {
    public EditText text1,text2,text3,text4;
    Button date,save;
    TextView textdate;
    DatePicker datepicker;
    ListView expenselist;
    private int myear,mmonth,mday;
    ArrayList<String> DayExpenseList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container,
            false);
        text1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        text2=(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        text3=(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        text4=(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        textdate = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        save = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        date=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.datepicker);
        expenselist = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(TopRatedFragment.this, mDateSetListener, myear, mmonth, mday);
                dpd.show();
            }
        });
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        myear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String entertainment = text1.getText().toString();
                String food = text2.getText().toString();
                String medicine = text3.getText().toString();
                String travel = text4.getText().toString();
                DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
                helper.insertValues(entertainment, food, medicine, travel);
                DayExpenseList = helper.getValues();
                setAdapter();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    private void setAdapter()
    {
        expenselist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,DayExpenseList));
    }

    private void updateDisplay() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        textdate.setText(new StringBuilder()
            .append(mday).append("-").append(mmonth+1).append("-")
            .append(myear));
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new 
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                myear=year;
                mmonth=monthOfYear;
                mday=dayOfMonth;
                updateDisplay();
            }
        };
}
```

Comment: Inside `Fragment`, Use `getActivity()` instead to get the `Context`.

Comment: If you're getting the errors you mentioned in just the code you've posted, then that's irrelevant. The constructors just need a Context passed to them; it doesn't matter if they're Activities or Fragments or not.

Comment: Why your getting the views? because views are inflated from  `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container,false);`, and Fragments binds with the activity context by default from which activity they are initiated. Second: Why DatePickerDialog gives exception? because date picker requires the context and your passing it the fragment instance, you can retrieve the context/activity anytime in a fragment by `getActivity()`. Hope it will resolve your query, and the exception as well.

Comment: Yes.I understood. The error has gone. May i know why i'am facing this error: constructor DatePickerDialog is undefined.

Comment: Use `getActivity()` instead of `TopRatedFragment.this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getApplicationContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29) is only available in `Context` and all classes that are extending it (including `Activity` and its variant). However, `Fragment` doesn't extend it, and hence, doesn't have that method.

Instead, `Fragment` depends on the `Activity`'s context, which can be accessed by calling [`getActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29).

The error says:

> 1. The constructor DatePickerDialog(TopRatedFragment, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, int, int, int) is undefined
> 2. create method getApplicationContext()

The first one is because [`DatePickerDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html#DatePickerDialog%28android.content.Context,%20android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) expects `Context` for the first argument, where you put `Fragment` which is not a subclass of `Context`.

The second one is already explained above.

Change the code to

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), mDateSetListener,
                               myear, mmonth, mday);
```

and

```
DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
```

should fix the errors.

Answer (score 0):

In fragment you use getActivity() not getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0):

In Fragment use activity's context,so change

```
    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

to

```
    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(container.getContext());
```

and use `ViewGroup container` as `final`

Or Use `getActivity()` to get activity context.