# How to call FragmentActivity from Activity inside TabHost?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have bit idea about `Fragment` but not in depth.I want to call `FragmentActivity` from Simple `Activity` via Intent.

My two File are as below,

- EventMain.java (extend Activity)
- EventDetail.java (extend FragmentActivity)

I am able to Run this if both `Class` extend `Activity`.

```
Intent i = new Intent(EventMain.this, EventDetail.class);
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) EventMain.this.getParent();
i.putExtra("event_id", EventId.get(position));
parentActivity.startChildActivity("Event_Detail", i);
```

But i want to integrate Google Map in `EventDetail.java` so i must have to extend `FragmentActivity`.

Right now i am calling same Intent as above and getting

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my_package}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout`

I got some Link but don't know how to manage with `TabHost(TabGroupActivity)`

**Update :**

Recently i get this

[How to start an intent that extends fragment, from a class that extends Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132532/solved-how-to-start-an-intent-that-extends-fragment-from-a-class-that-extends)

Its okay with simple activity but how to call under `TabHost`

Please Guys Help me & Guide me on right way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You must know that a FragmentActivity is an Activity, so you can start an Activity as a normal one.
So as the post you've linked says:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(EventMain.this, EventDetail.class);
startActivity(intent1);
```

Try to do that and tell us your result.

Comment: as i have mention in my question if i am calling same as way then getting error and that error is also post in my question link