# Call fragment from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have an activity with button on it and when a click i call the fragment with another button on fragment. but when click on fragment's button i cant call a second fragment. this is my source, pretty simple:
activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn_click"
    android:text="Call Fragment"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f0f0f0"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:text="Fragment 1"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn_frag2"
    android:text="Call Fragment 2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f0f0f0"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:text="Fragment 2"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment1);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

}
```

Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    }

    public void onClick2(View view) {
        Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment2);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Fragment2.java

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
    }
}
```

what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think now Fragment nesting is available just update the back computability  jar

now lets dig in the problem it self .

```
public void onClick2(View view) {
    Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment2);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

I think the `R.id.fragment1` belongs to a `TextView` which is not a good place to include child views in because its not a `ViewGroup`, you can remove the `textView` from the xml and replace it with a `LinearLayout` lets say and it will work , if not tell me what the error .

**fragment1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f0f0f0"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn_frag2"
    android:text="Call Fragment 2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

***Update for the error in the comment***

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
((Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_frag2)).setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =        fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment2);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

}
```

Comment: It's not working. I replace TextView with LinearLayout, first fragment opens fine, but when push the button on that fragment to open the second one the app halt with error
    Could not find a method onClick2(View) in the activity class com.example.fragments.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btn_frag2'

Comment: it's working, but i replace R.id.fragment1 with android.R.id.content and for back stack add fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

Comment: @JackDaniel What is the android.R.id.content, where to find content from above class?

Comment: This solution works when the changes suggested by @JackDaniel is incorporated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to replace the entire `Fragment1` with `Fragment2`, you need to do it inside `MainActivity`, by using:

```
Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment2);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Just put this code inside a method in `MainActivity`, then call that method from `Fragment1`.

Comment: with this, when i rotate the phone i lost the second fragment, and the first one gets on the screen

Answer (score 2):

This is my answer which solved the same problem. Fragment2.java is the fragment class which holds the layout of fragment2.xml.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                    Fragment  fragment2 = new Fragement2();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment2);
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();   
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a listener. Fragment1 calling the listener (main activity)

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me to call the parent_fragment method from child_fragment.

ParentFragment parent = (ParentFragment) activity.getFragmentManager().findViewById(R.id.contaniner);

parent.callMethod();

Answer (score 0):

**In MainActivity**

```
private static android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                     

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();                                                                 


    }

public void secondFragment() {

    fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_enter, R.anim.left_out)
            .replace(R.id.frameContainer, new secondFragment(), "secondFragmentTag").addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

**In FirstFragment call SecondFrgment Like this:**

```
new MainActivity().secondFragment();
```

Answer (score -2):

Just do that: getTabAt(index of your tab)

```
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.selectTab(actionBar.getTabAt(0));
```