# How to call a fragment itself on click same fragment

Tags: android

I am beginner, I need help to call fragment itself on click with different data,

when I am going to click on fragment itself the URL is not hitting again,
what i need to do?

```
public  void OnReceivablesSummeryOnClick(long tenantId,long userId)
    {
        Bundle bundle =new Bundle();

        bundle.putLong("TenantId",tenantId);
        bundle.putLong("SalesPersonId",userId);

        ReceivablesSummaryFragment fragment=new ReceivablesSummaryFragment();

        fragment.setFragmentActionListener(this);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.home_container,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();    
    }
```

**on click on the fragment**

```
if(mReceivableSummeryOnClickListener!= null) {
    SalesPersonWiseAgeingVO salesPersonWiseAgeingVO = mSalesPersonWiseAgeingVOsList.get(position);

    if (salesPersonWiseAgeingVO != null && !salesPersonWiseAgeingVO.getSalesPersonName().equalsIgnoreCase("Total")) {
                               mReceivableSummeryOnClickListener.OnReceivablesSummeryOnClick(mTenantId, userId);
     }
}
```

**In ReceivableSummeryFragment**
public void onAttach(Context context) {
super.onAttach(context);

switch (sum) {

```
case 1:

    if (context instanceof OnReceivablesSummarySelectionListener) {

        mReceivablesSummarySelectionListener = (OnReceivablesSummarySelectionListener) context;

    }

    break;
case 2:

    if (context instanceof OnReceivablesSummeryOnClickListener) {

        mReceivableSummeryOnClickListener = (OnReceivablesSummeryOnClickListener) context;

    }

    break;

default:

    throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()

            + " must implement OnReceivablesSummarySelectedListener");
```

}
}

**Onclick of Fragment**
Override

public void onClick(View v) {
    int num = 2;

```
switch (num) { //for hierarchy.

    case 1:

        if (mReceivablesSummarySelectionListener != null) {

            SalesPersonWiseAgeingVO salesPersonWiseAgeingVO = mSalesPersonWiseAgeingVOsList.get(position);

            if (salesPersonWiseAgeingVO != null && !salesPersonWiseAgeingVO.getSalesPersonName().equalsIgnoreCase("Total")) {

                mReceivablesSummarySelectionListener.OnReceivablesSummarySelected(mTenantId, salesPersonWiseAgeingVO.getSalesPersonId(),                                                     salesPersonWiseAgeingVO.getSalesPersonName());
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:

        if (mReceivableSummeryOnClickListener != null) {

            SalesPersonWiseAgeingVO salesPersonWiseAgeingVO = mSalesPersonWiseAgeingVOsList.get(position);

            if (salesPersonWiseAgeingVO != null && !salesPersonWiseAgeingVO.getSalesPersonName().equalsIgnoreCase("Total")) {

                mReceivableSummeryOnClickListener.OnReceivablesSummeryOnClick(mTenantId, userId);           
            }

        }

    break;
```

**Interface:-**

public interface OnReceivablesSummeryOnClickListener {

```
void OnReceivablesSummeryOnClick(long tenantId, long userId);
```

}

Comment: The above code working for calling fragment itself but that fragment URL is not hitting once again what need to follow help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call fragment from fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627829/call-fragment-from-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go .. you can call same fragment from itself as :

```
ReceivablesSummaryFragment innerFragment = new ReceivablesSummaryFragment ().newInstance("pass your data1", "pass your data2");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        innerFragment .setEnterTransition(new Slide(Gravity.RIGHT));
        innerFragment .setExitTransition(new Slide(Gravity.LEFT));
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.layoutContainer, innerFragment , title);// you can provide different title as you click on inner fragments
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(title);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And get the data in fragment as :

```
private String data1, data2;

 public ReceivablesSummaryFragment () {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


public static ReceivablesSummaryFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    ReceivablesSummaryFragment fragment = new ReceivablesSummaryFragment ();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("first data", param1);
    args.putString("second data", param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        data1= getArguments().getString("first data);
        data2= getArguments().getString("second data");
    }
}
```

It is working perfectly in my application .. Hope it helps .. Happy coding...

Comment: the fragment is displaying, but the URL data is not displaying on the fragment. and also getting the error on newInstance.