# While clicking a button how can i redirect to webview page in android fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    btnnext3=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnnext3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        private Context CurrentObj=getActivity();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent redirect=new Intent(CurrentObj,FurnitureFragment.class);
            CurrentObj.startActivity(redirect);
        }
    });
   return view;
}
```

Here it is not redirecting. while clicking the button app get stopped.Am using android studio. It is a fragment class

Logcat:

> E/AndroidRuntime(1952): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
>   Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {info.androidhive.navigationdrawer/info.androidhive.navigati‌​ondrawer.fragment.Fu‌​rnitureFragment};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? 07-11
>   03:59:47.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrum‌​entation.java:1628)

Comment: Post your logcat with error flag.

Comment: 07-11 03:59:47.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {info.androidhive.navigationdrawer/info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.FurnitureFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
07-11 03:59:47.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)

Comment: It Causes an error because you are calling a fragment from another fragment. Fragments cannot be called explicitly like activities. they have to be attached to an activity.

Comment: try `getContext()` instead of `getActivity()` and also make it global and non private

Comment: I tried this also.
try getContext() instead of getActivity(). Still its not working

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a Fragment through Intent. And this cannot happen. Because Fragments have to be attached or detached to the Activity.Please have a look at this for better understanding:
[Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)

**Replace your code:**

```
        Intent redirect=new Intent(CurrentObj,FurnitureFragment.class);
        CurrentObj.startActivity(redirect);
```

**With this:**

```
FurnitureFragment fragment2 = new FurnitureFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =        
fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment2);//Replace this with your layout ID.
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Check this out:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14628036/5192105