# How to add a fragment to activity, started from a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am starting `fragment A` from `Activity`, then starting `fragment B` from `fragment A`. But the problem is that `fragment B` is not showing added when calling `onActivityResult` on `fragment B`. And the `context` of `fragment B` is also getting null.

Code to start fragment A from activity,

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentA fragment = new FragmentA();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```

Code to start fragment B from fragment A,

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Is it added then disappears or not added at all?

Comment: As shown in code, i am replacing the fragment.

Comment: @Raja it is not duplicate at any chance, i am asking how to add a fragment to activity when started from a fragment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627829/call-fragment-from-fragment refer this link may be it helpful for you!

Comment: You just add 'addToBackStack(null)' in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of replacing fragment A with fragment B from fragment A, try replacing them in their activity itself.

```
((MyActivity) getActivity()).switchToSecondFragment();
```

And in the switchToSecondFragment method in activity :

```
public void switchToSecondFragment(){
     FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
     FragmentB fragment = new SelectTipFragment();
     FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
     transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
     transaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code in you activity's xml layout use **FrameLayout** as a container :-

```
    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
```

In your activity's java code write this code to add fragment

```
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_parent, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

Please note :-

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_parent, fragment);
```

will add the fragment in the container and

```
 fragmentTransaction .replace(R.id.main_parent, fragment);
```

will remove the previously added container and will add the new one [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18634392/5492047).

Now call the above function in your activity like this.

```
        TracksSubGridViewFragment tracksSubGridViewFragment = new TracksSubGridViewFragment();
addFragment(tracksSubGridViewFragment);
```

or in your fragment like this

```
TracksSubGridViewFragment tracksSubGridViewFragment = new TracksSubGridViewFragment();
     ((MainActivity) getActivity()).addFragment(tracksSubGridViewFragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` on `FragmentA`.

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentB fragment = new SelectTipFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager` is not available on fragmentA. It showing only two methods `getChildFragmentManager` and `getFragmentManager`

Comment: so. import `Fragment` from support library. not from `app`. import both  `Fragment` from same `package` . either `app` or `support library`. check on `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`.

Comment: What's the difference in both ?

Comment: If your `Fragment` is from `app` package then you should use `getFragmentManager() `but if from `support.v4` you should use `getSupportFragmentManager()`. Otherwise it will not work. check that first. I think `FragmentA` is from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`. But `FragmentB` from `android.app.Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

use below method for switching fragment from activity or fragment

```
public int switchContent(Fragment fragment, boolean isAddBackStack, String tag) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag);

        if (isAddBackStack) {
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
        }

        int commitID = ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        setCurrentTopFragment(Integer.parseInt(tag));
        return commitID;

    }
```

call this method like :

switchContent(mainListingFragment, false, String.valueOf(MAIN_LISTING_FRAGMENT));

int MAIN_LISTING_FRAGMENT = 1; // you can declare this in KeyInterface

```
public interface KeyInterface {
   int MAIN_LISTING_FRAGMENT = 1;
}
```

AND yes import following dependencies :

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```